# Directive included within Ng-show behave very wrong, otherwise it works

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I've put a [Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/alexrada/5u6Ls/) to showcase my error.

It's a multislider, based on [colResizable](http://quocity.com/colresizable/) plugin. The issue I have is that I need to display it with an ng-show, which renders it incorrectly if not displayed initially.

```
$scope.show = false; //initially set to false in controller


<div class="row" ng-show="show">
    <multirangeslider values="ranges" variances="variances" class="multislider-container row"></multirangeslider>
...
```

Please see the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexrada/5u6Ls/) (initially not working). When you change show value to true it works and it doesn't make sense. Why? How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

jQuery cannot calculate the width (or height) of a hidden element.  The colResizable plug-in uses jQuery's `outerWidth` function and gets zero back from it.  There are a number of ways to get around the issue -- the easiest is to use the `visible` style (you could write an ngVisible directive): http://jsfiddle.net/5u6Ls/5/

Alternatively, you can do something crazy like try and monitor when your element is visible and then apply the colResizable plugin, or there are also a number of workarounds on SO:

- [jQuery - Get Width of Element when Not Visible (Display: None)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1472303/jquery-get-width-of-element-when-not-visible-display-none)
- [Jquery/JS hidden elements dimention/position - with accordion and AJAX :(](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3600034/jquery-js-hidden-elements-dimention-position-with-accordion-and-ajax)